# Moving gradient colors for icons?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, font-awesome, vuejs3

I can produce moving gradient colors for text like so:

```
a {
  &:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, green, yellow, red, blue);
    background-size: 200% 200%;
    animation: gradient 2s ease infinite;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
  }
}
@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}
```

Now I have a moving gradient color effect (whose movement unfortunately can't be seen in a screenshot):

[image]

Font-Awesome icon color can be changed with the `color` property, which affects text but `-webkit-background-clip: text` seems to have no effect on icons.

Example of an icon:

```
<fa class="icon" :icon="[ 'fa', 'envelope' ]" size="1x"></fa>
```

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```css
.icn{
  font-size: 100px;
}

.color-icon:hover  {
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, green, yellow, red, blue);
    background-size: 200% 200%;
    animation: gradient 2s ease infinite;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" />

<i  class="fas fa-envelope icn color-icon"></i>
```